# How can i make my scripts wait for 15 minutes and resend code for verification, using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have a scenario where I am receiving an OTP for email and mobile verification , and the time limit for the OTP is 15 minutes, after 15 minutes if i am trying to use that OTP then i would receive an error message on the screen.

I want to automate the above scenario using JAVA(selenium), can anyone please suggest a better way to do this.

I have read few blogs, articles, watched some videos as well , and came across solutions like using selenium waits , thread.sleep , some also mentioned that we have to inject Javascript within the Web Browser, but i am not sure if these will be more feasible solutions to them.

Help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want wait exact 15 mins then go for thread.sleep . Why to over engineer it

Comment: Thanks for the response @PDHide . Its not about the over engineering , it just that i want to save that time, rather looking at an idle screen for 15 mins. Just trying to make it optimize , but yeah if nothing works i would go for Thread.sleep :)

Comment: what do you  want to do in that 15 mins ? can't you run that single test in parallel instead of making the entire test suite wait/

Comment: Hi @PDHide - Sorry for getting back so late on this. Yes i have used the same approach and wrote the e2e script. Thanks for your response.